# How to Modify String in Java (Volley Response)

Tags: android, android-volley

After modifying message I got "`hi`" in response from server after assigning value the value is lost when `getQuestionNO()` execution is completed and if I change the "`final Test test`" to "`Test test`" the in `getQuestionNo()` get error because in `onResponse()` it need final

**Test.java :**

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        Question question=new Question();
        getQuestionNo("nik",question);
        Toast.makeText(Test.this, question.getQue(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    void getQuestionNo(String email, final Question question)
    {
        String urlQueNo = PageConfig.QUIZ_QUESTIONNO + email;
        StringRequest stringRequest = 
                   new StringRequest(urlQueNo, new Response.Listener<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response)
            {
                question.setQue(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Test.this, 
                             "error on response1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
public class Question
{
    private String que="hi";


    public String getQue()
    {
        return que;
    }

    public void setQue(String que)
    {
        this.que = que;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can not have 2 public classes in same .java file.
It should be `class Question` instead of `public class Question`.

Answer (score 0):

Parse your response to POJO class and use it later on.